# Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in model file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my code in model..

```
function get_info($product_id)
{
    $this->db->from('product');
    $this->db->where('product_id',$product_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()==1)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
```

So many questions on stackoverflow but I Dont found any answer related to scenario. So what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Please check type of `$query`. I think it is returning false. and you are trying ->num_rows() on false. Also check if you are typing table name 'product' and field name 'product_id' correctly

Comment: Try to check using echo `$query->num_rows();` first & then check result. And also check query is working properly ....

Comment: Does `db::get()` return an object?  What does `echo gettype($db);` tell you?  Haven't used CodeIgniter but let us know what the type of `$query` is an it'll give a little more insight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your query is probably failing. Make sure database debugging in on and modify your code:

```
if ($query !== FALSE)
{
    // Run your code
    if ($query->num_rows() === 1)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
}
else
{
    // Check error
    echo 'Database Error(' . $this->db->_error_number() . ') - ' . $this->db->_error_message();
}
```

Comment: It doesn,t give a solution bu points me in right direction and I get my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have found nothing as a result, so query returns false. The other option is a problems with db connection, check it in config files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to execute any SQL queries? I suspect that your database connection doesn't work at all ... check your DB settings